# nativescript list-picker android 10 crush on

Tags: android, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, listpicker, nativescript-plugin

so there is a new problem with the new version of Android 10 
in emulator its API 29
every page that contains list-picker for now on will crush.
there is any solution to that? or I need to replace the list-picker with the list view? 
any estimation time how much time until there will be a new release with a fix to this issue?

currently, I'm using Naivescript v6.0.1

and this is the error that I'm getting when I'm trying to open the page with listpicker

java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mSelectorWheelPaint in class Landroid/widget/NumberPicker; (declaration of 'android.widget.NumberPicker' appear           s in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
 No field mSelectorWheelPaint

Answer (score 1):

replace app.gradle like :

```
    android { 
compileSdkVersion 29 
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2" 
defaultConfig { 
minSdkVersion 17 
generatedDensities = [] 
} 
aaptOptions 
{ additionalParameters 
"--no-version-vectors" 
} 
}
```

and replace to manifest like :

android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="505357"

and solved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated to the latest version of the runtime by using `tns platform update android`.

Additionally, make sure that you have the correct SDK platforms (Found in SDK Manager) ( and SDK build tools (SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Android SDK Build tools). Be sure to update to the latest if you haven't. This is what fixed my issues.